# Querying nested aliases with Mongoose

Tags: mongoose, aliases

Mongoose 5.3.3 - Querying aliases on simple fields works as intended.
Ex.

```
const userSchema = new Schema({h:{alias:"handle",type:String}});
const User = model("User",userSchema);
const user = new User({handle:"Jack"});
const query = {handle:"Jack"};
const users = await User.find(User.translateAliases(query));
console.log(users);
// prints [{...,handle:"Jack",...}]
```

But, for nested props, each with aliases, querying only performs when non-alias fieldnames are used.
Ex.

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    n:{alias:"name",type:{
        f:{alias:"first",type:String},
        l:{alias:"last",type:String}}}});
const User = model("User",userSchema);
const user = new User({name:{first:"Jack",last:"Swift"}});
const query1 = {"name.first":"Jack"};
const query2 = {name:{first:"Jack"}};
const query3 = {"name.f":"Jack"};
const query4 = {"n.f":"Jack"};
const users1 = await User.find(User.translateAliases(query1));
const users2 = await User.find(User.translateAliases(query2));
const users3 = await User.find(User.translateAliases(query3));
const users4 = await User.find(User.translateAliases(query4));
console.log(users1,users2,users3,users4);
// prints [],[],[],[{...name:{first:"Jack,last:"Swift"}...}]
```

I have also tried both 1) using the full dot path inline in the schema declaration

```
alias:"name.first"
```

instead of just "first", and 2) making the name property a separate schema.

```
const nameSchema = new Schema({f:{alias:"first"...
const userSchema = new Schema({n:{alias:"name",type:nameSchema}});
```

No dice. I want to believe the Mongoose team surely thought that folks would nest aliases so let's make more than just the top-level queryable, surely it's me lol. Can anyone drop a solution here, it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I have created a query map object that maps my alias dot paths to the non alias dot paths. Ex.

```
const queryMap = {"name.first":"n.f","name.last":"n.l",...};
```

It isn't the solution, but it works and as a side effect, allows for the rejection of queries that don't fit the map.